# How to send token in header and redirect in the same time: nodejs

Tags: node.js, redirect, routes

I have the following **login-route**, where I want to send the **token** to the **client** and then **redirect to another route**. This currently does not work.

How can I do that?

```
app.post('/login-user', (req, res) => {
        user.loginUser(req.body, (err, jResult) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(jResult)
            }
            let token = jwt.sign({
                user: jResult,
            }, "supersecret")
            console.log(token)
            res.send(token).redirect('/LimeLINE/chatroom')
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use passport.js middleware, which provide a way to redirect user when they are signed in or when they fail to.

```
 app.post('/login-user', passport.authenticate('your_strategy_name', {
        successRedirect : '/limeLINE/chatroom', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/login-user', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

## EDIT

This is my old answer

Use it as a middleware :

```
var logUser = function(){
    return function(req,res,next){
        user.loginUser(req.body, (err, jResult) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(jResult)
            }
            let token = jwt.sign({
                user: jResult,
            }, "supersecret")
            console.log(token)
            /* Store your token */
            next();
        })
    }
}

app.post('/LimeLINE/chatroom', logUser(), (req, res) => {
    /* code for your chat*/
})
```

To make this mandatory without making the middleware call at each route of you express applicationm dig around the Express Router.

Comment: but then what happens to my connection between the route `/login-user` which I am using in my ajax call on the front-end?

Comment: @July333 Oh, i didn't understand the question good, you're asking how to log user then to do things. I've update my answer